# TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-loader

After working through a major npm package update, I am getting an error thrown from my nuxt config file…

I haven’t found a link showing me transformAssetUrls current state (if it has been deprecated/renamed etc)

I ran into a similar issue with this line before

```js
vueLoader.options.transformAssetUrls['img'] = ['src', 'data-src']

vue loader defined here - const vueLoader = config.module.rules.find((rule) => rule.loader === 'vue-loader')
```

“options” defined here in the build process

```js
build: {
    extractCSS: true,
    plugins: [new VuetifyLoaderPlugin()],
    transpile: ['vuetify/lib'],
    babel: {
        presets({ isServer }) {
            const options = {
                // useBuiltIns: "usage",
                targets: isServer
                    ? { node: "current" }
                    : { browsers: ["> 1%",
                        "last 2 versions",
                        "not ie <= 8"],
                    }
            }
            return [
                [
                    require.resolve('@nuxt/babel-preset-app'),
                    {
                        buildTarget: isServer ? 'server' : 'client',
                        corejs: { version: 3 },
                        ...options,
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
```

Is this options setup out-dated? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to make a diff between before and after the update and look for the changes by going on the release page of each package and see what are the breaking changes.

Comment: @kissu are you mentioning git diff is the right way to proceed?

Comment: Yep, you can do thing or anything that gives you a diff.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in nuxt.config.js

```
build: {
   loaders: {
      vue: {
         transformAssetUrls: {
            video: ['src', 'poster'],
            source: 'src',
            img: 'src',
            image: 'xlink:href',
            'b-avatar': 'src',
            'b-img': 'src',
            'b-img-lazy': ['src', 'blank-src'],
            'b-card': 'img-src',
            'b-card-img': 'src',
            'b-card-img-lazy': ['src', 'blank-src'],
            'b-carousel-slide': 'img-src',
            'b-embed': 'src'
         }
      }
   }
}
```